# PDFs to Sharepoint 2013/Office 365

Tags: pdf

One of my clients have 1200 pdf documents which they are interested into extracting the content and putting on sharepoint pages. What is the best way to do it. OOB or 3 rd party.

Comment: Instead of going all the way and creating pages why dont you directly upload the PDFs and have OWA render them for you? would that not work and be a lot easier? (If you could convince your client)